# aria-describedby but the empty text error by default - is this correct?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

There is a good and trusted [example for `aria-describedby`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/ARIA21/form-alert3.html) when we need to show errors (when error happens, some elements get added to the DOM) and it becomes:

```html
<p><label for="email">Email address: [*]</label> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="err_1" class="error"> <span class="errtext" id="err_1">Error: Input data missing</span></p>
```

instead of

```html
<p><label for="email">Email address: [*]</label> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"> </p>
```

Is it fine **from the accessibility point of view**, if by default just the error text is empty? As result, when error happens, then just its text gets added.

By default (no error text) - does this code look correct?

```html
<p><label for="email">Email address: [*]</label> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="err_1" class="error"> <span class="errtext" id="err_1"></span></p>
```

So that we change the only text within the `span` from empty to some text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: is it fine from the accessibility point of view, if by default just the error text is empty? As result, when error happens, then just its text gets added.

Yes. This is discussed there : [Describing aria-describedby](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/09/describing-aria-describedby/#div-comment-4779) (it may cause a brief pause when reading the empty element)

Answer (score 1):

If the element that `aria-describedby` points to is empty, then nothing is read, so you're ok.  When you add text to the `<span>`, the text will be read when the user moves focus **back** to the input.  It will **not** be read as soon as you add the text.  You'd need `aria-live` for that (which would be a good idea).

```html
<p>
  <label for="email">Email address: [*]</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="err_1" class="error">
  <span class="errtext" id="err_1" aria-live="polite"></span>
</p>
```